# How to use mQueue in another class then MainActivity Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access mQueue from Volley in another class then MainActivity.java.

**MainActivity.java**

In `MainActivity.java` I create instance of RequestQueue and init the queue:

```
private RequestQueue mQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init queue ( getRequestQueue )
    mQueue = MyRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();

    getLights();
    initListView();
}
```

The method `getLight()` in MainActivity.java adds the request to the queue:

```
String url = APIkey + "/lights";
final MyJSONObject request = new MyJSONObject(Request.Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(), this, this);

// Executing the queue
mQueue.add(request);
```

**RequestHandler.java**

I moved the put requests to a separate class named RequestHandler.java.

```
public class RequestHandler implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

    RequestQueue mQueue;
    
    public void setLightOn(String lightId, boolean lightsOn){

        String url = APIkey + "/lights/" + lightId + "/state";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            json.put("on", lightsOn);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Error handling
            Log.i("Value was not found", "");
        }

        final MyJSONObject request = new MyJSONObject(Request.Method.PUT, url, json, this, this);

        request.setTag("ONOF");
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
    
    // Volley error and response handler
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        System.out.println("ERROR REQUEST HANDLER");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        System.out.println("SUCCEED REQUEST HANDLER");
    }

}
```

**ERROR**

Above code will give me an error and crash of my Android application.
Error that says mQueue is null;

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity .DetailActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'com.android.volley.Request
> com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a
> null object reference

Before this I had those methods also live in the `MainActivity` but would like to have it separate from my `MainActivity`.

What have I done wrong, forget so, so mQueue isn't null any more?

Answer (score 1):

The problem gets down to Java scoping.  Your `Activity` defines `mQueue` and tracks it, but you have created a class protected member field `mQueue` inside of your `RequestHandler` class.  However, the `RequestHandler` doesn't have a constructor which takes a `RequestQueue` as a parameter.

Alternatively, if your `RequestHandler` is an inner class of your `Activity`, then you do not have to define a `mQueue` member field as the inner class will have access to the parent class' member fields.

Comment: So if I understand you correct, I should declare mQueue already in the RequestHandler class?

Comment: No.  It depends on whether you have `RequestHandler` as an inner class of your `Activity`.  If you do, then just remove the line `RequestQueue mQueue` inside of the `RequestHandler` class.  If it is not, and the `RequestHandler` class is a stand alone class which lives outside of your `Activity`, then you need to create a constructor which has a `RequestQueue` parameter which you then set `mQueue` equal to in the constructor.